# When will "OnReconnected" occur?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

If "OnConnected" is raised when the 1st time we connect to our website, **when will "OnReconnected" happen?**

1) Suppose someone is connected to the network and suddenly the network isn't available and soon it recovers, so OnReconnected happens?

2) Any other special that will make OnReconnted happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Signalr documentation on [Understanding and Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) should have all the information you need.

Generally speaking OnReconnected will fire any time the SignalR client automatically reconnects to the SignalR server after it has lost its connection for any reason. These reasons can include network issues, the server restarting, etc...

The SignalR client will stop attempting to automatically reconnect to the server if it is unable to successfully do so within the `DisconnectTimeout`. If this happens, and you want to reestablish a connection, you will be required to manually restart the client by calling `start()` after the client becomes disconnected. If you manually restart the client by calling `start()`, `OnConnected` will be called instead of `OnReconnected` and the client will receive a new connection id.

Comment: Your link cannot be opened....Well, where to set DisconnectTimeOut? And do you mean if I didn't call "start()", and ReConnected will be automatically called if network is available?

Comment: OnReconnected will only be called if network is available within the specified time in the property DisconnectTimeOut. after this time connection will be dead forever until you have written logic to call start() method again.